# Adding to Javascript array based on if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, validation

I am needing to add error messages to an array based on the outcome of if statements. The code below brings back the second error message only when I input data that should trigger both. I know that .push() does not just add on to the previous array but the only way they had to fix that was making a for loop. I think there is some simple function somewhere I am just missing.

```
    $scope.error = {};
    if ($password == null || $vPassword == null || $email == null || $vEmail == null) {
        console.log('All fields must be filled in');
    } else {
        if ($scope.verifyPassword !== $scope.password) {
            $scope.error[scope.error.length()] = 'Your passwords must match...';
        }
        if ($scope.verifyEmail !== $scope.email) {
            $scope.error.push = ['Your email addresses must match...'];
        }
        console.log($scope.error);
    }
```

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory. Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

edit: I'm not sure what code produced the error I explained. Sorry. The code above was crap code I was messing with trying to get it to work. Obviously most of it doesn't make sense. The accepted answer was what I originally thought was producing that error but evidently it works. Sorry for the crappy post.

Comment: For an array: `$scope.error = []`; then just `.push("string")` as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push` is a function and should be invoked using `()`.

```
$scope.error.push('Your email addresses must match...');
```

Also, you cannot invoke `push` on an object that is not an Array.  You must instantiate `$scope.error` as an `Array`:

```
$scope.error = [];
```

Comment: I'm not as dumb as my questions makes me look. Read my edit to the questions. Thanks though! It works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$scope.error` into an array, not an object, then `.push()` will work appropriately.

```js
$scope.error = [];
$scope.error.push("Your passwords must match...");

console.log($scope.error);
```

Produces

```
["Your passwords must match..."]
```